# is pointed static_cast valid to avoid copying?

Tags: c++, c++11, static-cast

## update:

```
class foo {
public:

    foo() : x_(0) { std::cout << "foo constructor\n"; }
    foo(foo& c) : x_(c.x_) { std::cout << "foo copy- constructor\n"; }

    foo& operator=(foo const& c) {
        std::cout << "foo operator=\n";
        x_ = c.x_;
        return *this;
    }

protected:
    int x_;
};

class bar : public foo {
public:

    bar(int x) { foo::x_ = x; std::cout << "bar constructor\n"; }
    bar(bar& c) { std::cout << "bar copy- constructor\n"; }

    bar& operator=(bar const& c) {
        foo::operator=(c);
        std::cout << "bar operator=\n";
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {

    foo f;
    bar b(123);

    std::cout << "f = *static_cast<foo*>(&b);\n";
    f = *static_cast<foo*>(&b); // no copy constructor is called
    std::cout << "f = static_cast<foo>(b);\n";
    f = static_cast<foo>(b); // copy constructor and assignment is called
}
```

output:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -o main main.cpp && ./main
foo constructor
foo constructor
bar constructor
f = *static_cast<foo*>(&b);
foo operator=
f = static_cast<foo>(b);
foo copy- constructor
foo operator=
```

Is there an disatvantage of doing the static_cast like `*static_cast<foo*>(&b);` which is **not** calling the copy constructor as you can see in the output. see working example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb690dd5a8b08f33).

Comment: You mean not copy-initializable. Also, `*static_cast<base*>(&d)` is equivalent to the simpler `static_cast<base&>(d)`.

Comment: There's no way to instantiate any `base` or `derived` object in your example code. Your code deleted the copy constructor which also disables the implicit default constructor.

Comment: Delete this irrelevant fake code from your question, and place the real code here, not on some other site.

Comment: @user1810087 That's because operator= is being called... Initialization is not the same as assignment. Notice the `foo operator=` in your output.

Comment: @user1810087: That's because you're using the assignment operator, not the copy constructor. If you do the thing which you incorrectly claimed worked originally, it would try to call the copy constructor, and would not compile.

Comment: @user1810087 `f = static_cast<foo>(b)` calls your copy-constructor because `static_cast<foo>(b)` does a copy. That is equivalent to `f = foo(b);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the now completely different question:

```
f = *static_cast<foo*>(&b);
```

is equivalent to

```
f = b;
```

which calls `foo& operator=(foo const& c)` with no additional temporaries. However,

```
f = static_cast<foo>(b);
```

is equivalent to:

```
f = foo(b);
```

or

```
{
    foo temporary(b); // calls foo(foo const& );
    f = temporary;    // calls foo& operator=(foo const& );
}
```

which *does* create a temporary. Definitely prefer to do just:

```
f = b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the now-functioning code, this line:

```
base b = *static_cast<base*>(&d);
```

Is exactly equivalent to these two:

```
base b = static_cast<b&>(d);
base b = d;
```

In every case, we're calling `base(base const&)` with no temporary copies. `d` is just taken as a `const base&`.

There is a downside of doing this construction (outside of `static_cast` just adding noise), which is that `b` is *just* a `base` object. It is not of type `derived`. So if you had some virtual function `base::foo` that `derived` provided an override of, `b.foo()` would call `base::foo`. This is known as slicing. If you want to mantain the `derived`-ness through the assignment, you have to keep a reference or pointer:

```
base& b = d;
base* b = &d;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an disatvantage of doing the `static_cast like *static_cast<foo*>(&b);`

Yes. It's unnecessary noise. Just do this:

```
f = b;
```

It has the exact same effect.

Comment: @user1810087: I'm not sure why you're giving me that link. I'm the one who should be giving that link to you, since you are repeatedly disregarding the "Self Contained, Correct" part.